# Query to filter a table based on a comparison applied to the same table?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group, temporary-tables, query-performance

**Case & Problem:**

Consider a corporate building with some rooms and departments that need authorization to enter.
Employees have to scan their badges to be authorized.
If the employee is inside (*the badge was already scanned*), the system warns her/him accordingly and does not open the door.
And the supervisor should be able to see and/or report all employees who are in a particular room at any given time.

Checking whether the employee is inside or not was somewhat trivial with the help of a couple of StackOverflow/StackExchange answers.

My problem is at the reporting stage.
The question is how can I filter the table to show those who are currently inside the given point, in a performant way.

**Current Situation & What I've Done So Far:**

My backend code is looping over all the records and check if they're inside, one by one.
Yet, I suspect that this is not ideal (*I might be wrong, though*) performance-wise and/or for modularity/responsibility concerns; in the future, I'll need to allow other client applications to connect to the database without having them write their own code/logic to check or report the inside status.

Sample Table:

```sql
+-----+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+
|  id | code     | point         | action    | timestamp       |
+-----+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+
|   1 | 11111111 | Department A  | pass_in   | 1561369024008   |
|   2 | 11111111 | Department A  | pass_out  | 1561369024007   |
|   3 | 11111111 | Department A  | pass_in   | 1561369024006   |
|   5 | 22222222 | Department B  | pass_in   | 1561369024005   |
|   6 | 22222222 | Department A  | pass_out  | 1561369024004   |
|   7 | 22222222 | Department A  | pass_in   | 1561369024003   |
+-----+----------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Sample Code:

```js
var point = 'Department A';
var recordsInPoint = helper
                        .fetchAllRecords()
                        .filter( record => helper.isInside( record, point ) );
```

Query to check if inside:

```sql
SELECT
    ( count_compare.count_in > count_compare.count_out ) AS is_inside
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(`id`)
        FROM 
            scanner_log
        WHERE 
            `code`='11111111' AND 
            `point`='Department A' AND 
            `action`='pass_in'
        )  AS count_in,
        (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(`id`)
        FROM 
            scanner_log
        WHERE 
            `code`='11111111' AND 
            `point`='Department A' AND 
            `action`='pass_out'
        ) AS count_out
) AS `count_compare`;
```

**Questions:**
• How can I move the reporting logic from backend to database?
• Would it be really faster and less resource-hungry if handled by db server?

**Ideas & Options:**

• Create a stored procedure and carry the backend logic to db as is by looping over all records.
I don't see much benefit on this, to be honest. Same loop method, just performed by db server. Also, there's a major drawback as I don't have just one table for logs, there are separate tables for each building or company. And I can't pass the table name as a parameter, as far as I know mySQL / MariaDB doesn't support this. I have to use PREPARE QUERY and EXECUTE QUERY commands which sounds a little bit overkill to me.

• Create another nested temporary table and join them somehow to filter but I just couldn't get my head around it, really, nothing.

Thanks for all your help and insights.

Comment: "looping over all the records..., one by one". -- That's thinking like a programmer.  Learn to think like a DBA, where a single SQL query can act on an entire table.  _That_ is the primary way to get performance.

Comment: @RickJames, I agree, I got to learn to think more like a DBA when it comes to DB stuff and I'm trying to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this one, I recommend having two tables:

- `History` (like what you have).  This is a list (a la audit trail) of everything that has happened (INs and OUTs).
- `Current` -- The latest place where each person is.

`History` has an ever-growing number of rows, and is probably not relevant for the Question at hand.

`Current` contains one row per person.  A simple `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause should pick out all the persons that are "IN" (or "OUT").

"separate tables for each building or company" -- No.  This is the third time today I have advised against having multiple identical schemas.

On the other hand, `Current` and `History` may have the same columns.  This is an exception to the previous paragraph.

Do not split by department or building.

Comment: About the _multiple identical schemas_, each `logs` table will have about 8-9 million rows per year and there are more than hundred _buildings_.  
If combined, one table will have to handle hundreds of millions logs per year. From this perspective, isn't it better to separate these?  
Especially, given that I'm a novice when it comes to db management; I know next to nothing about sharding and other fancy stuff.  
Now, I'm hearing you say that _then go learn stuff or find someone who knows_ :))

Comment: @EnderNafi - you have manually "partitioned" the data.  And you are living with the hassles of constructing the right table name for each query.  Although having a single table would be simpler, I don't necessarily recommend it _now_, since there would be pain in doing the transformation.

Comment: @EnderNafi - My Answer assumed are just starting out and did not already have a billion rows, so I was pushing you in what I think is the optimal direction.  Your Question sounded like a "groupwise-max" problem, which is messy to do and likely to perform poorly -- The History/Current split addresses performance there.  Are there other queries that should be taken into consideration?  With a target of a billion rows, we need to look at _all_ queries _together_.

Comment: Splitting by building or department provides _virtually no_ performance.  Ditto for `PARTITIONing`.  How much data do you already have?

Comment: Firstly, I've created a `current` table as you suggested and made necessary changes to other parts of the application; it works great, so far. Second, the application is not in full production-mode, just pilot (testing) departments. That is, all data I have currently is expendable which is about 100k rows of logs ( `history` ) and much less in other tables. Third, each scan (and getting a response) requires 5 queries at worst and still I can get a response in under 40ms. including the network-latency. Processing of the backend takes usually 6-7ms.

Comment: Following your advice in your latest comment as _no performance benefit of splitting / partitioning_, I'll ditch the structure of _multiple schemas_ and combine them in _one table per purpose_. I suspect what I've done is kind of a _premature optimization attempt_. I'm going to monitor the system and I'll try and handle any performance bottlenecks whenever (if) I encounter one.

Comment: @EnderNafi - "Premature optimization" is the common cold of programming.  Another common one is "but I indexed every column".  There can still be traps in the advice I gave you; hopefully 100K rows will be enough to show whether your `SELECTs` need further help.  Let me know; I enjoy scaling challenges.